# On Generalization of Nicomanchus' theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's recall Nicomanchus' theorem states that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{3} = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$$
Also, I have shown that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{5} = \left(\left(\frac{n(n^2-1)}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)^2}{6}\right) + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2 - \left(\frac{n(n^2-1)}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)(n-1)^2}{6}\right)^2 $$
We clearly see a pattern here which made me conjecture that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{2p+1} = \left(A+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2 - \left(A\right)^2 $$
I have posted the conjecture here http://vixra.org/abs/2104.0165

-**Question:** assuming the conjecture is true, how significant can it be and besides, has this been conjectured before?

Comment: Formulas for $\sum_1^nk^r$ have been known since the time of the Bernoullis. I'm sure you can find such information one the web.See, e.g., https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/sums-of-powers-of-positive-integers-jakob-bernoulli-1654-1705-switzerland and https://thekeep.eiu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2898&context=theses and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123728/discussion-on-question-by-shuaib-lateef-on-generalization-of-nicomanchus-theore).